# SQL application error

Tags: sql, database, embedded-sql

here is a code in embedded SQL(in c)

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION
char *id = NULL;      
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION
.
. //here id is assigned value, printf("%s",id) gives an int i parsed into string
.
EXEC SQL SELECT * FROM table T WHERE T.id = :id
```

This code gives the following error,

> SQLCODE : 4294966876
>   SQL0420N  Invalid character found in a
>   character string argument of the
>   function "DECFLOAT". 
>   SQLSTATE=22018

Can any tell what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

The datatype `char` is not the same as `string`. In PostgreSQL (and probably any other RDBMS) `char` holds a single character. You cannot assign the string representation of an integer > 9.